# Redirect web server port behind VPN

Tags: vpn, port-forwarding

Just recently started using a VPN that allows open ports above 2048. I host my own web server on port 80.

I need help configuring my web server to run on a port above 2048 but get redirected to port 80 so people don't have to write the URL like myserver.com:2049

Would virtual hosts do this? What would be the best step-by-step configuration for this?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do that. If they don't forward port 80 to you, you can't get traffic on port 80. Thus people will have to include the port number.

And no, really. There is nothing *you* can do to change that.

Comment: Ok thank you for the answer.